# creating views from two or more tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to create a view that list department_id,department_name,department_employees,total_dept_salary for a specific department_id

Comment: I want a pony and free pizza. Did you have a **question**?  (If you have a SELECT statement, that can be the basis for creating a view. But *why* do you want to create a view? What *problem* does that solve?)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW theview AS
    select department department_id,department_name,department_employees,total_dept_salary
    from table1 join table2 using (department_id);
```

This assumes that what joins the two tables is department id. If the tables have no common column, use the ON clause instead. In either case, it would be helpful to know what columns each table contains.

Als, [check this out](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp) for more info on creating view syntax.